# Importing simulation from ParaView to ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, image, format

I made a simulation and reworked the output with **[ParaView](http://www.paraview.org/)**. I simulated an avalanche on a DEM and what I want to do is to compare the area of the simulated avalanche with that of the real avalanche. To do this I would use ArcMap 10 where I already have the real area as a shapefile.

How can I bring what I have on ParaView to ArcMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to export files from Paraview, but simulations ?

You need formats that can be imported by ArcGIS (I don't use it, see [Paraview supported formats](http://paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Data_formats)).

Another solution is [Paraview GEO](https://sites.google.com/a/objectivity.ca/paraviewgeo/), for the exploration and mining industry with many others geological and mining formats ([supported format](http://paraviewgeo.objectivity.ca/documentation/user-manual/supported-formats)), but I see nothing about ArcGIS.

You can also use Paraview with [GRASS GIS](http://grass.osgeo.org/) or [R](http://www.r-project.org/):

- From Paraview to GRASS GIS (in 3D):

[image]    -----------> [image]

- From Paraview to R (in 3D):

[image]  -----------> [image]

Or GRASS GIS alone  (gif from [Two-dimensional dam break flooding model](http://istgeo.ist.supsi.ch/site/projects/dambreak))
[image]